# OpenCV - Bee detection using Cascades repository fails

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, cascade, image-recognition

I am trying to find/make a cascade to recognize bees. Does one already exist?

I have been looking on the internet, but there are only face/animal recognition.
Also I tried to do it my self with 20x20 images, but it didn't recognize bees very well.

I want to do something like this:

[image: Bee Recognition]

These are my results so far, I was trying to compare a template image with every frame, but it detects too many points, and wrong points.

[image: Too Many points]

Comment: Show us what you tried by posting your working cascade code and an example bee and photo-shopped result you want to have. From there some of us can help you in the right direction. We might need to work on your question title once you posted code...

Comment: Now you got the images there but what about the code? Post it too so we can see what you did... Use ctrl-k once you selected your code for formatting it.